# nearer pairs to a special point

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as data which is uploaded [here](https://files.fm/u/g3rhb28p?k=7f3768d4), due to its long length.  We 
 can consider to the list as a collection of `{x,y}` pairs.

Please consider a value for example `3.63`, above this value we first arrive `4.814` (we called it `y2`), and below this value we first arrive `3.08` (we called it `y1`). As far as we can see, they `(3.08 and 4.814)` are `y` with any `x`.

I want to access `{y1,y2,y2-y1}` that are the nearer `y`s to a special value which is `3.63` here. For example I found here the triple collection is `{3.08, 4.814, 1.734}`.

In a plot we can show the aim as the below plot in which `y1` and `y2` are highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Please make your question more precise (e.g., by using correct grammar to phrase it). I don't get what you are looking for. What is `y1` and `y2`?

Comment: y1 and y2 are the y's of two pairs {x1,y1} and {x2,y2}, (just their y's are important which must very close to the value 3.63)

Comment: you need a precise definition of what you mean by "nearer"

Comment: What does "close" mean here? Please give additional information in the post, not in the comments.

Comment: why would you use `Get Coordinates` when you have the actual input data available?

Comment: Ok I am trying to modify the question.

Comment: It is confusing that you have highlighted a pair of points at the same x. Are you looking for a pair like that or can the ys be at different x?

Comment: You are right, they can be in different xs

Comment: @InzoBabaria Is `{3.63, 3.63, 0}` the correct output, if one of your `{x,y}` has `y == 3.63`?

Comment: In fact, this is too rear case. We have to check, The mentioned special value (here 3.6) is mostly in the interval between the upper bond and the lower bond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two y-values that are nearest to `3.63` are extracted below along with their difference:

```
data = Import["rereimport.dat"];
{#, #2, #2 - #} & @@ Nearest[data[[All, 2]], 3.63, 2]
```

> ```
> {3.08, 3.055, -0.025}'
> ```

The following gives instead one y-value above 3.63, and one below 3.63:

```
With[{ys = Union[data[[All, 2]]]}, {#, #2, #2 - #} & @@
   Nearest[ys, First[Nearest[MovingAverage[ys, 2], 3.63, 1]], 2]]
```

> ```
> {3.08, 4.831, 1.751}
> ```

Comment: Your answer seems to have a bug. For example: `SeedRandom[5]; data = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
near = RandomReal[10];
With[{ys = Union[data[[All, 2]]]}, 
 Nearest[ys, Nearest[MovingAverage[ys, 2], near, 1][[1]], 2]]` produces a bracket that doesn't include the target.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest). The following answer is similar to my [`LeftNeighbor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154942/45431) function from [Given an ordered set S, find the points in S corresponding to another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154893/45431):

```
Bracket[data_] := Module[{ord = Ordering[data], s},
    s = data[[ord]];
    BracketFunction[s, ord, Nearest[s->"Index"]]
];
Bracket[data_, list_] := Bracket[data][list]

BracketFunction[s_, o_, nf_][list_] := With[{n = nf[list][[1]]},
    With[{lindex=n - UnitStep[s[[n]] - list]},
        o[[{lindex, lindex+1}]]
    ]
]

BracketFunction[s_, o_, nf_][list_List] := With[{n = nf[list][[All, 1]]},
    With[{lindex=n - UnitStep[s[[n]] - list]},
        Transpose@{o[[lindex]], o[[lindex+1]]}
    ]
]
```

`BracketFunction` returns the indices of the data that bracket the input. For example:

```
bf = Bracket[data[[All, 2]]];
indices = bf[3.63]
data[[indices, 2]]
```

> {391, 402}
>
> {3.08, 4.831}

where I only return the `y` values here. `BracketFunction` also works with lists of data:

```
indices = bf[{2.2, 3.63}]
data[[#]]& /@ indices
```

> {{396, 395}, {391, 402}}
>
> {{{2.2845, 1.969}, {2.3422, 2.255}}, {{2.5731, 3.08}, {2.5731, 4.831}}}

where I return the `{x, y}` values this time.

If desired, one could add a [SummaryBox](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77658/45431) format to `BracketFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple way to get the nearest point above and below.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];
SortBy[data, 1/(# - 3.08) &][[{1, -1}]]
```

> {3.03482, 3.13265}

caveat, this throws an error if any data point exactly equals the special value.