# Finding the index of an element to be inserted in a sorted list

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I have a sorted list with no duplicates:

```
L = {1, 2, 5, 7, 8}
```

Given an integer `n`, I want to find the index of `n` if it is to be inserted into `L`.

I have been using

`Length[Select[L, # <= n &]]`

But that is incredibly unoptimal as I should be able to do this in $\log n$ by bisecting the set. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[pos0, pos1, pos2, pos3]
pos0[l_, n_] := Total@UnitStep[n - l]
pos1[l_, n_] := LengthWhile[l, # < n &]
pos2[l_, n_] := Ordering[Ordering[Join[{n}, l]]][[1]]
pos3[l_, n_] := If[n <= Length[l]/3, pos1[l, n], pos2[l, n]]


L = {1, 2, 5, 7, 8};
{pos0[L,3], pos1[L, 3], pos2[L, 3], pos3[L, 3]}
```

> {2, 2, 2, 2}

Answer (score 3):

You could use a variation of my [LeftNeighbor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154942/45431) function, although it returns the left neighbor strictly less than the number instead of less equal as in your solution:

```
LeftNeighbor[s_]:=LeftNeighborFunction[s,Nearest[s->"Index"]]
LeftNeighbor[s_,list_List]:=LeftNeighbor[s][list]
LeftNeighbor[s_, elem_]:=First@LeftNeighbor[s][{elem}]

LeftNeighborFunction[s_,nf_][list_List]:=With[{n=nf[list][[All,1]]},n-UnitStep[s[[n]]-list]]
LeftNeighborFunction[s_,nf_][elem_]:=First @ LeftNeighborFunction[s,nf][{elem}]

MakeBoxes[i:LeftNeighborFunction[s_,nf_], StandardForm] ^:= Module[
    {
    len=Length[s],
    g = FirstCase[ToBoxes[nf], _GraphicsBox, GraphicsBox[Point[{0,0}]],Infinity]
    },
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
        LeftNeighborFunction,
        i,
        RawBoxes@g,
        {
        BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Data points: ",Length[s]},StandardForm],
        BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Range: ",MinMax[s]},StandardForm]
        },
        {},
        StandardForm,
        "Interpretable"->True
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
L={1,2,5,7,8};
lnf = LeftNeighbor[L];

lnf[5]
lnf[Range[0, 9]]
```

> 2
>
> {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}

It should be possible to modify the code to return the left neighbor that is less equal than the requested number if desired.

**A remark on performance**

The construction of the `LeftNeighborFunction` can be slow, but if you want to find the index of many numbers into the same list `L`, then you will only have to construct the `LeftNeighborFunction` once. Here is a comparison with a large list:

```
L = Sort @ RandomReal[100, 10^6];
```

The construction of the `LeftNeightbor` is a bit slow:

```
lnf = LeftNeighbor[L]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.052, Null}

But finding the index of many numbers is very fast:

```
sample = RandomReal[100, 10^3];
r1 = lnf[sample]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00020, Null}

Compare this with one of kglr's solution:

```
r2 = pos0[L, #]& /@ sample; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {3.05, Null}

Check :

```
r1 === r2
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the issue of how to handle inappropriate inputs is as important finding the position of an integer that is in the list being considered. Therefore, I would write something like this:

```
positionOfN[data : {__Integer}, n_Integer] := 
  First[First[Position[data, n], Return[$Failed]]]
positionOfN[_, _] = $Failed;
```

#### Testing

```
data = {1, 2, 5, 7, 8};
positionOfN[data, 5]
```

> `3`

```
positionOfN[data, -5]
```

> `$Failed`

```
positionOfN[data, 5.]
```

> `$Failed`

```
positionOfN[{"foo", "bar"}, 5]
```

> `$Failed`

#### Note

If you don't want `$Failed` to be returned as the failure value, substitute whatever value you like for the two occurrences of  `$Failed`.